# Add property to folder

Tags: jenkins, artifactory, rpm-spec

I have a spec file in Jenkins uploading artifacts to Artifactory repository path `test-local/web/develop/web-DEVELOP-12/` where `12` is the build number from Jenkins.

All artifacts are uploaded under `web-DEVELOP-XX`. I would like this folder to have the same properties as the artifacts such as `vcs.revision`, `build.timestamp`, `build.name`, `build.number`. Here I only get those properties in the artifact files under `web-DEVELOP-XX` folder, but I would like to also have those properties to the folder `web-DEVELOP-XX`.

Is it possible to do this from Jenkins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're correct that currently Properties set using a file spec are not set on the root folder.
you can add (at the end of your current set props) a simple curl command to set the properties on the folder. 
For ex, this will set a property a=b on "all-my-frogs" **folder** under my-local-repo repository:

```
PUT http://rtserver:port/artifactory/api/storage/my-local-repo/all-my-frogs?properties=a=b&recursive=0
```

note: recursive=1  will set the properties on all files under the folder as well as the folder itself, so you can consider that as your solution (instead of spec)

Comment: Thanks. That seems to be the only solution. I wanted to do it from the spec file but I the folder is not part of the build so no buildinfo included unless I add it using the api